# Cordova 2.1.0 app won't run in Xcode 4.5.1

Tags: cordova, xcode4.5

I've created a Cordova 2.1.0 app it is building and running fine on simulator with the terminal command (~/cordova/emulate). However when I try to run it from the Xcode it is building fine but won't run. I am using Xcode 4.5.1.

Thanks

Comment: I think we need more information: Error messages, code...

Comment: There is no error message. when I try to run the project it just shows `Build Succeeded` but won't launch simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I feel like an idiot for all the steps I went through trying to track down this same problem.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled so many things unncecessarily.  I'm betting this is your problem.

The "scheme" dropdown menu bar near the top left of the Xcode window is actually two dropdown menus, even if it doesn't look that way.  Right now it probably says "CordovaLib>iPhone 6.0 Simulator"  or something like that (depending on which simulator or device you're trying to deploy to).  Normally you click on the dropdown menu and get a list of simulators and devices available to choose from.

What you (and I) never noticed is that in the past it always said "yourProject>iPhone 6.0 Simulator" where yourProject is the target (i.e. your project name).  Click on the "CordovaLib" portion of text and it will give you a different dropdown menu to select your project.  Then you click on the simulator portion of the dropdown menu to select the device you want to deploy to.  Hit run and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my problem was that the executable of my project in the `Scheme->run` was set to `None` somehow (so basically there was no .app to run, that's why the simulator didn't open up) when I selected my `sampleProj.app` as executable it worked.